# SoapUI ¿Cómo se generar dinámicament el password de una petición?

Tags: webservice, script, soap, soapui, peticion

Necesito generar una contraseña para la petición dinamicamente, porque se necesita concatenar con un timestamp y codificarlo con SHA-256 para obtener el password.
La pregunta sera donde crear el script para generar este password y como añadirlo a la petición o variable que lea la petición.

Hay alguna forma de generar ese password en cada petición?

Answer (score 0):

SoapUI tiene acceso completo a lenguaje Groovy, por lo que se puede codificar en un script Groovy dentreo de test step.
El tema de la variable se puede almacenar en una propiedad, donde SoapUI ofrece varios ambitos a elegir según las necesidades (Global, TestSuite, TestCase, TestStep) y luego se pueden llamar desde la petición concreta. Ejemplo para TestCase ${#TestCase#passwordVar}.

El problema es que se tendra que ejecutar el step Groovy antes de realizar la petición SOAP, pero puede hacerse en el nivel de test case, o en un loop en Groovy, en función de la estructura del proyecto.

Opciones Groovy script:

- does calculations or SQL to get input values
- sets properties
- calls the SOAP steps
- extract required response values from resp XML in a loop.

Ejemplos [Groovy scripts](https://www.soapui.org/docs/scripting-and-properties/tips-tricks/)

```
log.info "prova script"
//Global
def globalProp = context.expand('${#Global#name}')
log.info ("Global property password is: " + globalProp);

//Project
def projProp = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("name")
log.info ("Project property user is: " + projProp);

//TestSuite
def testSuiteProp = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue("name")
log.info ("TestSuite property user is: " + testSuiteProp);

//TestCase
def testCaseProp = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("name")
log.info ("TestCase property user is: " + testCaseProp);

//TestStep
def testStepProp = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties").getPropertyValue("name")
log.info ("TestStep property user is: " + testStepProp);
```

Además de código Groovy, se pueden utilizar clases del api java añadiendo import al script o añadir archivos propios .jar (con classes java) a la carpeta /ext que son accesibles desde dentro del classpath.